# CI: Argument Count Error in join 2 tables

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a project & I've encounter with this problem "Argument Count Error". I've checked code by code but did not find anything.

Controller Code :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Appointment extends CI_Controller
{
       public function __construct()
       {
              parent::__construct();
              $this->load->model(['appointment_m', 'jadwal_m']);
       }

       public function index($id)
       {
              $dokter = $this->appointment_m->getProfileApp($id);
              $jadwal = $this->appointment_m->getJadwalApp($id);

              $data = [
                     'dokter' => $dokter,
                     'jadwal' => $jadwal
              ];

              // var_dump($data);
              // die;
              $this->load->view('frontend/appointment/appointment', $data);
       }
}
```

Model Code :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Appointment_m extends CI_Model
{
       public function getProfileApp($id = null)
       {
              $this->db->from('tbldokter');
              if ($id != null) {
                     $this->db->where('id_dokter', $id);
              }
              $query = $this->db->get()->row();
              return $query;
       }

       public function getJadwalApp($id)
       {
              $this->db->join('tbldokter', 'tbldokter.id_dokter = tbljadwal.id_dokter');
              $this->db->from('tbljadwal');
              $this->db->where('tbldokter.id_dokter', $id);
              $query = $this->db->get();
              return $query;
       }
}
```

modal name process :

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: ArgumentCountError
>
> Message: Too few arguments to function Appointment::index(), 0 passed
>   in D:\xampp\htdocs\dental-web\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532
>   and exactly 1 expected
>
> Filename:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\dental-web\application\controllers\Appointment.php
>
> Line Number: 12
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: D:\xampp\htdocs\dental-web\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

I've search over this site related this type problem but I did not find my problem solution. This problem comes before submit form. Please Help me.

Thank You

Comment: The reason behind this In Appointment controller you add a parameter in index method . Are you passing id in index method when using this method?

Answer (score 0):

Your index is need to receiving an ID, did you pass the ID to it? If not, then the error will shown to you.

Answer (score 0):

if the $id of the index() function in controller is mandatory, then you have to make sure it always exist. if not, try defined $id = null, so if the $id is absent, you will not get error.

Answer (score 0):

Error message clearly says that Argument count is less than arguments required by your index function in your Appointment Controller. To make an argument optional assign some default values to that argument like:

```js
public function index($id = NULL){
  // your code here
}
```

Now you call this method with or without parameter.

One more thing that you have to know is: index method is the default method of that controller, means if you call your controller in config/routes.php without any method the index method is called by default. Such as:

```js
$route['yourController'] = 'yourController';
```

http://yourDomain/yourController in this case the index method is called by default.

OR

```js
$route['yourController/(any:)'] =  'yourController/$1';
```

In this case index method will be called with a parameter.